# partition mounting issue with custom recovery Android

Tags: android, linux, system, linux-device-driver

I have ported a custom twrp recovery for my device and now the sd-card and internal storage is not mounting . Can anyone tell me inorder to mount sd card and internal storage what i have to write in recovery.fstab?

Comment: Hey and welcome to stack overflow - you got downvoted because your question was not so good - read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

hey you havent provided enough information like which phone twrp version 
by experience it looks like you havent flashed required decrypt zip which caused twp not able to read your storage properly